# Returning several NSString

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parameters, nsstring

I would like to create a method which returns several NSString. I am thinking of this kind of method but I do not find it in the objc style, rather C programmer style - it uses pointers to (NSString*), thus (NSString**):

```
- (LONG) readOwnerInformationToNationalNumber:(NSString**) nationalNumber
                                   toName:(NSString**) name
                              toFirstName:(NSString**) firstName
                            toNationality:(NSString**) nationality
                           toPlaceOfBirth:(NSString**) placeOfBirth
                            toDateOfBirth:(NSString**) dateOfBirth
                                 toGender:(NSString**) gender
                        toStreetAndNumber:(NSString**) streetAndNumber
                                    toZip:(NSString**) zip
                           toMunicipality:(NSString**) municipality
                             toChipNumber:(NSString**) chipNumber
                  toCardValidityDateBegin:(NSString**) cardValidityDateBegin
                    toCardValidityDateEnd:(NSString**) cardValidityDateEnd
               toCardDeliveryMunicipality:(NSString**) cardDeliveryMunicipality
```

In the method body, I return strings like this:

```
*nationalNumber = [NSString stringWithString:@"11223344"];
```

In fact, it is the first time I have returned multiple NSString and always return my NSString as a return parameter.

Is that an ugly, not robust or feasible way of doing ?

Regards,
Apple 92

Answer (score 4):

What you do is certainly possible but I don't find it very elegant. The information you need to return seems to belong together, so why don't you create a custom class that includes all these fields and have your method return an instance of that class?

Comment: I have just tried it and it works. Your idea of making a new class would indeed enable to gather the fields but I still would have to pass a pointer to that class (because I want to keep the LONG C-Style return code). It would be in the style - (LONG) readOwnerInformationToDataRecipient:(Recipient**) theRecipient

Comment: Or just use NSDictionary for both output of the method. All of that is just key-value.

Comment: @user255607: Why do you want/need to return a `long`?

Comment: I return a long to warn the caller of the result of the search process.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "Cocoa way" would be to return an NSDictionary if you don't want a custom class:

```
- (NSDictionary*) readOwnerInformationToNationalNumber
{
    // do stuff

    NSDictionary* returnedDictionary 
        = dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              nationalNumber,           @"nationalNumber",
              name,                     @"name",
              // etc ...
              cardDeliveryMunicipality, @"cardDeliveryMunicipality",
              nil];

    return returnedDictionary;
}
```

This is used in Coca in a number of places e.g. [NSURL -resourceValuesForKeys:error](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)